# Xdebug stops working after "valet secure"

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, laravel-valet, xdebug-3

I have a problem related to **Laravel Valet** and **Xdebug**. The Xdebug stops working after `valet secure` command. The Xdebug was installed through PECL with Homebrew and works fine with unsecured sites. After running `valet secure` the Xdebug stops working (it still works for `php artisan` commands though). Tested with PhpStorm.

I use Laravel Valet 2.15.0, Xdebug v3.0.4

My Xdebug configuration:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.20/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: After `valet secure`, do `xdebug.mode` and `xdebug.start_with_request` have the same values in `phpinfo()` run through the web server? It they do, try configuring [Xdebug remote log](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collect-xdebug-logs) and share its contents

Comment: @EugeneMorozov It's just `xdebug.log` now, no longer `xdebug.remote_log`: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_log

Comment: @Derick It's described in the doc, but perhaps we should change the default tab from Xdebug 3 to Xdebug 2. Will do.